# Problema no envio de emails com Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

Estou tentando enviar email com a classe Mail do Laravel da seguinte maneira.

Código:

```
Mail::send('companies.emails.register', ['company' => $company], function ($m) use ($company) {
   $m->to($company->email, $company->name)->subject('Cadastro de Construtora!');
});
```

Configuração:

```
MAIL_ADMIN=email@admin
MAIL_ADMIN_NAME=Contato
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=email@email
MAIL_PASSWORD=****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Erro:

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]
```

Acho que o problema não é no código, mas sim em alguma config do servidor mas não faço ideia.

Comment: Parece estar certo. Vc já autorizou na sua conta do gmail para permitir aplicativos "menos seguros"?

O link é: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps, basta marcar a opção.

Comment: Já tinha feito isso e mesmo assim o erro continua.

Comment: Sua aplicação laravel está em qual ambiente?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28433816/how-to-fix-could-not-open-socket-in-zend-mail-zend-framework-2/28436702#28436702

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei o problema, era um bloqueio da minha hospedagem, a digital ocean por padrão bloqueia o envio de emails.